# Android Studio - How to check if fragment is inflated

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

In my Android Studio project I have a TabView as a fragment of a Navigation Drawer Activity.

Fragment:

```
public class TabView extends Fragment {

View inflatedView;
TextView tvBalance;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.delivery, container, false);
    getActivity().setTitle("TabView");

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab_1"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab_2"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab_3"));
    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    viewPager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter
            (getFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount()));
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

    return inflatedView;
}

public void updateBalance(String balance) {
    if (inflatedView != null) {
        tvBalance = inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.tvBalance);
        tvBalance.setText("$" + balance);
    }
    Log.d("updateBalance", balance);
}
```

The UpdateBalance method is called in my MainActivity everytime the value changes. This works well as *Log.d(...)* prints the right value at the right time.

Somehow the Textfield does not change as *if (inflatedView != null)* is never true, although the fragment is displayed on screen.

Why is *inflatedView* allways null and how to avoid this problem?

Comment: Sounds like the fragment that's displaying and the fragment you are using in your main activity to call `updateBalance` are two separate instances of the fragment class. How are you obtaining a reference to the fragment in your main activity?

Comment: From where and how do you call `updateBalance` from your activity?

Comment: in `onCreate` and with `TabView frag = new TabView();` `frag.updateBalance(Balance)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using TAGS when placing a fragment, and findFragmentByTag to test afterwards is a fragment is inflated... For example:

```
// Loading the fragment with a tag:
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.content, new HomeFragment(), "HOME_FRAGMENT");
ft.commit();

// then later check if the fragment is there:
HomeFragment fHome = (HomeFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("HOME_FRAGMENT");

if (fHome != null && fHome.isVisible())
{
    // my fragment is inflated and visible
}
```

Comment: How to tag a fragment?

Comment: I edited the answer showing how to load a tagged fragment